# Restrict Videos stored on S3 to be only accessible from Android app

Tags: android, amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

Flow:

- App sends the authorized API request to server for getting the videos list
- server returns the url

============================

Setup:

- Videos stored on AWS S3
- Videos Should be only Accessible to Android APP

=============================

Ways I found so far:

1. Use CloudFront with signed URLs - 
   Problem - if someone gets access to signed URL then he/she can access the content. Also signed URLs are valid for some time if the video length is more than decided time then, what?
2. Use CloudFront and cookies for URL
   problem - Should I generate the cookie on android or what should be the correct flow?

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible.  You must send content to someone... they can intercept it in a number of different ways.  There's nothing you can do about this.  The best you can do is limit your exposure by using signed URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Use CloudFront signed URLs.

The expiration time is only checked at the **beginning** of the download for web distributions, so it only needs to be valid long enough for the download to start.  CloudFront doesn't interrupt the download if the URL expires after that. See [When Does CloudFront Check the Expiration Time of a Signed URL?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-check-expiration)

A short expiration time and using HTTPS, together, effectively solves the problem of the URL becoming discovered and reused.

Additionally, if you use a [custom policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html) rather than a canned policy, you can generate a signed URL that is only valid when used from a single client IP address.  Add this if you are still concerned about unauthorized use of your signed URLs.

Signed cookies are not more secure than signed URLs.

Comment: This is the right answer.  You can use signed URLs with S3 directly though... CloudFront doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Though its old answer, but I got curious to know that to get signed URL from cloudfront every time won't be an overhead???

Comment: @user1405309 not really, but that is an understandable misconception.  Signed URLs are not something you *get* (from the service) -- they're something you *generate* using a secret key, entirely done in your code with no interaction with the service when the URL is generated.  The asymmetric nature of the signing algorithm means that when the URL is used, the service can later validate that the URL was generated with the correct private key, while effectively preventing reverse-engineering of the key from the attached signature.